# Open Object Rexx - ooREXX

Tags: shell, scripting, oorexx

ooREXX is a scripting language produced by IBM for OS/2. It is also available    for various operating systems: Linux, Solaris, Windows. I just want know  what are the benfits of ooREX compared to other scritping langunages such as Shell or windows powershell?

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of the language 'Shell' so cannot comment on that. Windows Powershell is windows only and although powerful is, apparently, a bit of a beast to learn.

OORexx is not from IBM, it is from the Rexx Language Association. It originated in IBM as ORexx, which itself was developed from Rexx (now referred to as Classic Rexx), but was released to Rexx L.A. who now maintain and enhance it (as OORexx). It is simple to use but powerful. It is also cross-platform. And you do not have to use the OO features - the interpreter will generally execute 'classic' Rexx programs without change.

I would not call it a scripting language - it is a general purpose programming language. I have written a text editor in it as well as standard application programs. In fact I hardly use it as a scripting language.